# How to tell sed to delete a matching pattern?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a large numbe of lines and i want to delete a pattern from `\ParallelLText{\story{Arnam Kangsai}}{\jverse{14}  }` to get `\ParallelLText{\story{Arnam Kangsai}}{   }`. How do i tell to sed delete from `\jverse` to `}` first matching after `\jverse`   using `i` option

Comment: Please share your last best attempt to  see what the issue is.

Comment: `cat FILE | sed 's/\\jverse{14}//'` or, using -i `sed -i 's/\\jverse{14}//' FILE`. Personally, I'd never use -i, but always redirect to a temp. file, inspect that, and then move that to the original file. That's just me though.

Comment: it should be general because in my case there may not be 14 also inside `\jverse{14}` @Roadowl

Comment: @Roadowl -- that's what `sed -i.bak ...` allows. It preserves the original in `filename.bak`. Of course, there is nothing wrong to redirecting to a tmp file to examine before replacement `:)`

Comment: @BikiTeron will there always be a `\jverse{[0-9][0-9]*}` present? (matches 1-or-more numbers between `{...}`)

Comment: Can `{\jverse{[0-9][0-9]*}  }` appear in any other lines but those with, e.g. `\ParallelLText{\story{Arnam Kangsai}}{\jverse{14}  }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat FILE | sed 's/\\jverse{[0-9][0-9]}//'
```

or, using -i

```
sed -i 's/\\jverse{[0-9][0-9]}//' FILE
```

or, if there can be between one or more digits:

```
sed -i 's/\\jverse{[0-9]\+}//' FILE
```

Comment: POSIX BRE does not include `'+'`. (though some provide `'+'` as an extension), POSIX Extended regex does, so `sed -r` would work in your last case. Or simply `[0-9][0-9]*` to match one or more, or `\{1,\}`.